# Strip text from string in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I have the variables below in a large and important SH file and I need to remove some data from a variable and keep only part of the text.

I get "repoTest" with a link to an internal git repo and I need the variable "nameAppTest" to only receive the constant data after the last "/".

**Example:**

**I get:** `repoTest="ssh://git@code.br.repo.local/code/ecsb/name-repo.git"`

**I try to do a split:** `nameAppTest=$(echo "$repoTest"|cut -d'/' -f5|sed -e 's/.git//g')`

**Response I get:** `echo "$nameAppTest"` (ecsb).

**What I expect to receive:** name-repo

I tried like this and failed: `nameAppTest=$(echo "$repoTest"|cut -d'/' -f5|sed -e 's/.git//g')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nifty trick:

```sh
nameAppTest=$(basename "$repoTest" .git)
```

Uses [`basename`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/basename.1.html) to get just the last component of the URL, and strip the extension all in one step.

You can also use `sh` parameter expansion to do it in two steps without any external programs:

```sh
# Remove everything up to and including the last /
temp="${repoTest##*/}"
# Remove the trailing .git
nameAppTest="${temp%.git}"
```